# Can't find Denoiser in 2.81a

Tags: denoise

My Splash screen and system-info.txt both confirm I have version 2.81 of Blender.
[image]
[image]

And yet, when I go to View Layer Properties and Passes I cannot find the sector Data underneath and therefore I also cannot find the Denoiser.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in Eevee. Switch to Cycles, if you want to enable denoising data.

[image]